# App Engine >60 seconds backend processing?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an appengine app which receives pubsub messages.

I am processing the data which might take more than 60 seconds.

Since the request handler is [limited](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/how-requests-are-handled#Java_The_request_timer) for 60 seconds, I acknowledge the pubsub straight away and then do the processing.

Though this does not help - the messages I send are retried again and again (I see in  the logger) even though the processing was done.

here is my code:

```
public class Handler extends HttpServlet {


@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException  {


    // Acknowledge the message by returning a success code
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    resp.getWriter().close();

    JsonParser parser = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance().createJsonParser(req.getInputStream());
    parser.skipToKey("message");

    PubsubMessage message = parser.parseAndClose(PubsubMessage.class);
    log.info("request was received " +  message.getMessageId());
    String payload = new String(message.decodeData(), "UTF-8");

    doSomthingWithPayload(payload); // this takes more than 60 seconds
}

}
```

I tried using task queue, but since my data is very large I get `Task size too large`

questions:

1. is this the right way to acknowledge the pubsub?
2. can the process take more than 60 seconds  after acknowledging?

   - if yes - why is my pubsub message resent again and again?
   - if not: what can I do as a work around - while I cannot use task queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to let your servlet thread go ASAP. In your code you writing response and than doing payload processing on servlet thread. Instead immediately after you received request you should parse and store payload to datastore, initiate async processing (via task queue), set status HttpServletResponse.SC_OK and return from `doPost`. If you will use datastore to store your payload you will not hit task size limit because you will be able to put in task only datastore record ID, not all payload.

Comment: can I use google-storage instead of datastore? Will the storage process take less than 60 seconds?

Comment: also as I understood from the docs - 
A request handler has a limited amount of time to generate and return a response to a request, typically around 60 seconds.  so cant I reply and then continue as done in my code above? waht is this 60 seconds limit about? about the response reply? or also the processing afterwords?

Comment: 1. You can try to use Cloud Storage instead of Cloud Datastore if you prefer so.
2. In your code above you are writing reply and continue to use servlet thread after that. So in your approach 60 seconds time limit applies to `doSomethingWithPayload` call.

Comment: 3. To get rid of this limitation you should return control from `doPost` early. This is why I propose to do bare minimum on servlet thread: parse payload, write it to some persistent store, post task to queue for async processing and return from `doPost`. 
In my approach lengthly `doSomethingWithPayload` call will happen not on a servlet thread but on queue worker thread, so you can work around servlet request handling time limit (60 s).

Comment: Note that a task can run for up to 10 minutes, if you use App Engine standard runtime, or up to 24 hours :) on flexible runtime.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin  so the 60 seconds limit is not for replying to pubsub, but for the whole processing? (if I do not use the task queue)

Comment: Any request on standard runtime should complete in 60 seconds, unless it's a task in a task queue.