# AppEngine “Task size too large”

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am running an app on appengine and am creating tasks.

```
    Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
    queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/worker").param("data", payload));
```

when my payload is very large (717.3 kb) I get this error:
`"Task size too large”`

what is the size limit for tasks on appengine? didn't find this in the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Maximum task size is 100KB](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Task_Queue).

Note that tasks are serialized and stored in the Datastore. Passing a lot of data into a task can be inefficient. You may be better off storing the data in the datastore, and then passing only the parameters to a task (e.g. an entity key, etc.)

Comment: I need the data to be stored in storage at the end. Is it ok if I store in storage instead and send the file name instead of using datastore? and is the storge process guaranteed to take less than 60 seconds ?(due to appengine time limit) see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272594/app-engine-60-seconds-backend-processing/41272903?noredirect=1#comment69748064_41272903) question

Comment: I cannot answer these questions without knowing your requirements. Both Datastore and Cloud Storage are very fast.

Comment: why not use memcach? which is better to use datastore or memcach?

Comment: these are my requirements: I am receiving large data to my appengine app which should be stored in GCS, have some processing on data and ten inseted in bigquery.
since the whole process might take more than 60 sec I need to pass the data to taskqueue.

Comment: Is there any way to print to the log how large a task is when it runs? I want to see if my tasks are getting close to that limit.